# Unwanted extra right space in HTML layout

Tags: css, layout, html

I am designing a HTML layout using tables. On the left column, I want an image with 10px on top and bottom. Unfortunately, there are a couple of pixels added by the parent `div`. I don't know why. I am including a picture:

[image]

I have also created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rWUD9/) to replicate the issue. I cannot spot an issue in my CSS. Does anyone know what is happening? What am I missing? What is the solution? Thanks!

Comment: "I am designing a HTML layout using tables." — Don't, that isn't what tables are for. *Tables should not be used purely as a means to layout document content* — http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html

Comment: The widths of your columns don't match the total table width that you specified. When I remove the total table width, it works for me. (But what Quentin says)

Comment: Honestly, I found tables much easier to use than embedded divs when layout is a bit sophisticated... Pekka, I am not sure what you mean by 'removing the total table width'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is due to your image actual `width` which is 161px approx. and your div width is 163px approx. You need to add `width:100%;` in your img style.

[***Working Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/rWUD9/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set the width of the image. `div.leftColAd` is 163px x 248px and your image is 160px x 239px

Comment: I thought that by setting this 160px width at the #leftCol level, that would set the width of the child div too...